# How to do paging in the loop?

Tags: categories, loop, pagination

I used `single.php` for this code:

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
    $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
    $args=array(
        'category__in' => $category_ids,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'showposts'=>6, //Gösterilecek yazı adeti
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $benzer = new wp_query($args);
    if( $benzer->have_posts() ) {
        while ($benzer->have_posts()) {
            $benzer->the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="urundetaykutu">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>  
    <?php } } wp_reset_query(); }?>
```

This code working, but I want to use pagination in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1, // this will get the right posts for the current page (i.e. if the user loads www.domain.com/blog/page/2 directly)
'posts_per_page' => '6'
```

to your `$args` and delete `showposts`

`showposts`is deprecated.

[From the Codex reference for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> `showposts` (int) - number of posts to show per page. *Deprecated* as of Version *2.1* in favor of `'posts_per_page'`.

Add Pagination links:

```
<?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts' ); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
```

Comment: ok, but pagination not work. Only, three posts show.  I want to do paging in this code.

Comment: You have to add pagination links. I've edited the answer. Working now?

Comment: add pagination links but not work. added(pagination links) to the bottom of the code. here after; <?php } } wp_reset_query(); }?>   '<?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts' ); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>'